# How can i print lines from multiple files sequentially?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that given an array of text files, it prints all lines that share the same index on the same line, for example:

file1:

hey

there

file2:

1

2

output:

hey 1

there 2

I can't seem to find a way of iterating through the lines of all the files like someone would do on an array. This is where i'm stuck at:

```
void paste(FILE** files,int argc){
    int maxLines = getMaxLines(files,argc);
    int line = 1;
    //char buf[256];
    char ch;
    for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++){
        for (int j=1; j<argc; j++){
            while ((ch=fgetc(files[j])) != '\n'){
                putchar(ch);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        line++;
    }
    //printf("%d",maxLines);
}
```

Obviously it doesnt do what is intended but i think i have the main idea captured in that piece of code. How can i use the line index to iterate through lines? How can i access each line this way?

Comment: What does getMaxLines do?  Does it read through the files and count the lines?  And if so, does it reset the file pointer to the start?  It's probably better not to get the line count; just read the files.  If one of the files is exhausted, don't provide output (or possibly abort the loop, although that would be surprising behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that prints a line from a file - basically, your `while` loop (no need for line index, since the position in the file is persistent, meaning that each time you call the function for some file, the next line will be printed).

Now iterate over the files, printing one line from each, again and again, until one of them reaches eof.